# How to change selected item color of accordion item in react native?

Tags: react-native, accordion, jsx, native-base

I've done an accordion list using `native-base`.I'm trying to change the color of accordion content when selected.But what I'm getting is there will be a default selection on the first item in the accordion. Also if I close one accordion and open another the selection of item will be on same position of previous one.Following is the code please help me to find a solution.

**code**

```
onPressList = (item, index) => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate("Header2", { id: item.id, name: item.value })
    this.setState({ pressStatus: true, selectedItem: index });
  }

....
....
<FlatList
          data={drop_down_data}
          extraData={this.state.selectedItem}
          renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
            const { selectedItem: sd } = this.state
            const localColor = { color: sd === index ? "#cc0000" : "black", fontWeight: sd === index ? "500" : "100" }
            return (
              < ListItem >
                <TouchableOpacity
                  style={{
                    padding: 5
                  }}
                  onPress={() =>
                    this.onPressList(item, index)
                  }>
                  <Text style={localColor}>{item.value}</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              </ListItem>
            )
          }}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
        />
```

Comment: Can you please share this component `state`?

Comment: You're talking about accordion, but you didn't provide any code that contains the `<Accordion>` container. Your code worked ok for me, showing a list and assuming your `drop_down_data` is something like `[{value="Text 1"},{value="Text 2"}]`. I just had to click on the Text itself to make it red and bold.